# Rails: How does .clear differ from .destroy?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Does .clear invoke callbacks? Does it just empty the array of objects but not delete them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're talking about calling `clear` or `destroy` on an ActiveRecord association (if so, please provide those details in your question).  In that case, `clear` does not run callbacks, and `destroy` does.  See [ActiveRecord::Associations::ClassMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Associations/ClassMethods.html).